# Extract article from website to text using Beautifulsoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the title, article, date posted, and author from this article to text using Beautifulsoup. Actually from more articles from this website but I guess the layout is the same for all the articles? Since I don't have any knowledge in HTML I don't know how to proceed.

http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/mp-vill-snabba-pa-miljardsatsning-pa-svaga-skolor/

I have inspected the HTML code, but don't understand it. I think if someone could post code for this I can figure out how to extract additional information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

the_url = requests.get("http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/mp-vill-snabba-pa-miljardsatsning-pa-svaga-skolor/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_url,'html.parser')

title = soup.title
article_headline = soup.find('h1',{'class':'article__headline'}).text
```

I couldn't find the Article itself(not logged in), nor the author nor the date posted. But pretty much you locate the element let's say
[This ONE](http://prntscr.com/f6qj73) you got the tag and the container as shown in the picture (box). How will we find that tag in BeautifulSoup `a = soup.find('div',{'class':'article__lead'})` and we saved it in a variable **a**. Now if we wanted the paragraph(text) we can simply say `print(a.p.text)` where .p gets us the paragraph and the .text gets us only the text without tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should try inspecting the HTML code for the data you want, try locating in the HTML code for the author name, a simple `Ctrl+F: Hans` in source code will do it. You will see that the first time `"Hans"` can be found in source code is in this piece of code:

```
<div class="js-article"
     data-page-title="Milj&#246;partiet vill f&#229; med miljardsatsning p&#229; skolor redan i h&#246;stbudgeten - DN.SE"
     data-article-url="/nyheter/sverige/mp-vill-snabba-pa-miljardsatsning-pa-svaga-skolor/"
     data-authors="Hans Ros&#233;n"
     data-section-display-name="Sverige"
     data-article-friendly-id="dn.epi.1739446"
     data-article-title="MP vill snabba p&#229; miljardsatsning p&#229; svaga skolor"
     data-article-publish-date="2017-05-11"
     data-article-publish-time="19:53"
     data-is-premium="true"
     data-access-level="Limited"
     data-is-standalone="false"
     data-article-main-section="nyheter"
     data-article-sub-section="sverige">
```

Notice the **date** and **title** of the article are already in this piece of code. The next to step is to learn the Python code to extract this piece of information from the website, we can start with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/mp-vill-snabba-pa-miljardsatsning-pa-svaga-skolor/")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

article_data = soup.find("div", class_="js-article")
```

Now we can do this to extract the precise data:

```
title = article_data["data-article-title"]
date = article_data["data-article-publish-date"]
time = article_data["data-article-publish-time"]
author = article_data["data-authors"]
```

Try a similar approach to extract the entire body of the article, you'll see that the body is inside `div class="article__body-content"` in source code, and to extract that we can simply use `soup.find()`:

```
article_body = soup.find("div", class_="article__body-content")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to get started! And for the quick reply.

Comment: A much better reply. Note that Lamar your post will probably get removed. It's not a question that's looking for a solution. You're looking for someone to do it for yourself and that you can reuse.
Therefore the question is too broad(not specific nor helpful) to you. 
It would be better to learn Python and BeautifulSoup, there are a lot of Youtube videos, very helpful. Please come back with a more specific question,

Comment: @FaultyFuse Exactly, I thought of flagging the question, but I tried to explain how to parse html when he has no idea where to look for in the code for the data he wants.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Yeah :), I felt like helping too and explaining but for someone with no background, I just feel like he's going to copy-paste and not learn anything. Your answer was much better than mine but I see no way for him to move forward after giving him an answer without a lot of details on how BeatifulSoup works.